# ¿Cómo generar 10 arrays e introducirlos a un nuevo arreglo?

Tags: java

Hice el siguiente código y me generó 10 arreglos de 10 elementos, ahora lo que quiero hacer es copiar esos arreglos a uno nuevo. Ayuda, por favor y gracias!

```
public static void main (String args[]){
        int a []=new int[10]; //Arreglo de 10 elementos, estoy probando con 10 elementos.
        Arreglos obj = new Arreglos(); //Esta instanciación es para facilitarme el llenado del arreglo.
        int i = 0;
        while (i<10) {
            obj.llenaVectorRandom(a,3);
            i++;
            System.out.println("Array: "+i);
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.println("Elemento: "+(j+1)+" :"+a[j]); //Hasta aquí me devuelve 10 arreglos de 10 elementos (o eso parece), pero ahora, ¿Cómo copio todo eso a un nuevo arreglo?
            }
        }
```

Comment: A un nuevo arreglo de cuantos elementos? 1?

Comment: No. Lo que quiero es copiar todos los elementos que se generaron de esos arreglos a un arreglo nuevo. Es decir, en vez de que sean 10 arreglos por separado, sólo sea un arreglo que contenga todos los elementos de los 10 arreglos.

Comment: Esta linea me los generó: System.out.println("Elemento: "+(j+1)+" :"+a[j]); Los imprimí para ver si funciona, pero lo que quiero es que esos elementos que imprimí me los guarde en un array.

Comment: Obligatoriamente quieres que sean Arrays?o pude ser arrayList?requiere menos quebraderos de cabeza, te lo intento solucionar

Comment: Me parece que tu codigo no genera 10 vectores sino que llena el mismo vector 10 veces con diferentes datos. Cada vez que se llena el vector se pierde el llenado anterior. Para la pregunta me parece que tendrias que aclarar si lo que querés como resultado es una matriz de 10 x 1.000 o un vector de 10.000 elementos. No se entiende muy bien.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Juan. Supongo que lo mejor es crear una matriz de dos dimensiones. `int[] [] = new int[10][1000];` y llenarlo con un un bucle for aninadado en otro. Tendrías de primeras una lista con todo lo que necesitas. Pero no me queda muy claro si es esto lo que quieres por tu código.

Comment: Asi es, seria un vector de 10.000 elementos donde esos 10.000 elementos son los que se generaron en los 10 arreglos. Espero me hayas entendido. Ósea: primer acto: genero 10 arreglos con 1.000 elementos, segundo acto: lo elementos generados de esos 10 arreglos se pasan a un sólo vector, es decir, ese ultimo vector tendrá 10 mil elementos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te ha comentado Juan arriba, en tu código estás rellenando el mismo array una y otra vez. Para crear 10 arrays tienes que guardar esos valores generados aleatoriamente en algún sitio, de forma, además, que no sean sobrescritos.

Lo que se me antoja más sencillo es crear un array que contenta subarrays. Esto es, un array multidimensional. En nuestro caso, de dos dimensiones. En él guardaremos los valores para luego pasarlos a una sola lista.

Antes de exponer el código. Un array bidimensional tiene la siguiente forma:

```
array[2][5] = {
                 [00, 01, 02, 03, 04],
                 [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
              }
```

Por ejemplo, el 13 estaría en la posición `array[1][3]`.

Una vez visto esto, vamos al código:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[][] arrays = new int[10][1000];
        int[] g_array = new int[10000];
        int contador = 0;
        Random r = new Random();

        // Rellenamos la lista bidimensional
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
            {
                arrays[i][j] = r.nextInt(11);
            }
        }

        // Con otro bucle for, pasamos la lista 
        // bidimebsional a una lista unidimensional
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
            {
                g_array[contador] = arrays[i][j];
                System.out.println(g_array[contador]);
                contador += 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Como te he dicho, creo que esto es lo más fácil para lo que pides.

Añadir, por último, que ambas operaciones podrían haberse llevado a cabo en un solo bucle for:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[][] arrays = new int[10][1000];
        int[] g_array = new int[10000];
        int contador = 0;
        Random r = new Random();

        // Rellenamos la lista bidimensional
        // y la pasamos a la unidimensional
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<1000; j++)
            {
                arrays[i][j] = r.nextInt(11);
                g_array[contador] = arrays[i][j];
                System.out.println(g_array[contador]);
                contador += 1;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes razón, está más fácil de esa forma. Por cierto si me sirvió! Muchísimas gracias Felipe. Y también a los demás que comentaron, en verdad me ayudaron un buen. Saludos!